# Creating a table, which, upon click, updates textfile

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I am trying to create a website which allows for people to check current "points" that they have and the reason they received those points. E.G: Received 5 points for taking out rubbish, Received 10 points for washing dishes.

Although I have set up the actual points system and a database for usernames and passwords, I cant for the life of me work out how to implement a front end way for admins to add points, and give reasons, which will show up on the user page once he is logged in.
Any help would be appreciated
Thank you

Comment: Added some code to the answer below which should get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a form (in html) that has a drop down of the users, a text box for the reason and a text box for the points with a submit button. When clicked it returns to a php file on the server that takes the info either using `$_GET` or `$_POST` and then using `mysqli_` php functions updates the mysql database. The php file can then display success/failure and any other information you might want to display back to the admin.

Hopefully with these steps you can use google and find appropriate code that actually makes it happen and if you do get stuck, come back here, show what you have so far and people will be happy to help.

**EDIT:** It's Christmas and I felt like writing some code, so here is a rough start for you that works. There is quite a bit that you will be able to improve on. You will also want to create a report to be able to show how it's all going, but that's probably a bit to much for here. Good luck and enjoy.

```
<?php
/*
This script expects the following to be in place:
1. A mySQL server on the same server as the web server running this script
2. A database called 'tasks' with a username called 'tasks' and a password of 'YourPassWordHere'
3. The following table within the database (SQL included here so can copy/paste into phpMyAdmin to create it:
USE `tasks`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `transaction`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transaction` (
  `id_transaction` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_child` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_task` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_transaction`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
*/

function echoHTMLHead($title) {
    echo '
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.25">
        <style type="text/css">
            #main {
                width: 230px;
            }
            #myForm1 {
                font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-size: medium;
                background-color: #FFFFCC;
                border: medium inset #808000;
                border-radius: 8px;
                width: 95%;
            }
            #myForm2 {
                font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-size: medium;
                background-color: #FFFFBB;
                border: medium inset #808000;
                border-radius: 8px;
                width: 95%;
            }
            #myForm3 {
                font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-size: medium;
                background-color: #FFFFAA;
                border: medium inset #808000;
                border-radius: 8px;
                width: 95%;
            }
            #error {
                font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-size: medium;
                color:red;  
                text-align:center;
                font-style:normal;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
            #success {
                font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
                font-size: medium;
                color:green;    
                text-align:center;
                font-style:normal;
                font-weight:bold;
            }
        </style>
        <title>'.$title.'</title>
    </head>
        ';
}

/* Main part starts here */
// first we check to see if we have data or is this the first time the page is called
if ((isset($_POST['id_child'])) && (isset($_POST['id_task'])) && (isset($_POST['txtPoints'])) && (isset($_POST['txtAdminID']))) {
  // We have data come from the form so we process it.
  // Get the data recieved and put it into variables
  $id_child = trim($_POST['id_child']);
  $id_task = trim($_POST['id_task']);
  $txtPoints = trim($_POST['txtPoints']);
  $txtAdminID = trim($_POST['txtAdminID']);
  /* Now check if admin ID is what it should be and just in case someone  see's this code, we're going to encrypt the AdminID and check it against a pre- encrypted code
     To create a hash create a seperate php file with
  <?php
     $txtAdminID = "12345";
     echo hash('sha256', $txtAdminID);
  ?> */
  $txtKnownAdminHash = "5994471abb01112afcc18159f6cc74b4f511b99806da59b3caf5a9c173cacfc5";  // which for the example code is the hash of 12345   
  $txtHashedAdminID = hash('sha256', $txtAdminID);
  if ($txtKnownAdminHash != $txtHashedAdminID) {
    // didn't match so we display an error but display the form again to allow admin to try again

  echoHTMLHead("Tasks and Rewards - Data entry error");
?>
    <body>
        <div id="main"> 
            <p id="error">You are not authorised!!</p>
            <form id="myForm1" accept-charset="utf8" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="myForm1"> 
                <label id="lblPerson" for="id_child" form="myForm1">Person </label>
                <select required id="id_child" name="id_child">
                    <option value="">Select from the list...</option>
                    <option <?php if ($id_child == "1") echo 'selected '; ?>value="1">Trevor</option>
                    <option <?php if ($id_child == "2") echo 'selected '; ?>value="2">Patty</option>
                    <option <?php if ($id_child == "3") echo 'selected '; ?>value="3">Aaron</option>
                    <option <?php if ($id_child == "4") echo 'selected '; ?>value="4">Elian</option>
                </select><br />
                <label id="lblTask" for="id_task" form="myForm1">Task </label>
                <select required id="id_task" name="id_task">
                    <option value="">Select from the list...</option>
                    <option <?php if ($id_task == "1") echo 'selected '; ?>value="1">Wash dishes</option>
                    <option <?php if ($id_task == "2") echo 'selected '; ?>value="2">Clean room</option>
                    <option <?php if ($id_task == "3") echo 'selected '; ?>value="3">Put out trash</option>
                    <option <?php if ($id_task == "4") echo 'selected '; ?>value="4">Mow lawn</option>
                    <option <?php if ($id_task == "5") echo 'selected '; ?>value="5">Water garden</option>
                    <option <?php if ($id_task == "6") echo 'selected '; ?>value="6">Special task</option>
                </select><br />
                <label id="lblPoints" for="txtPoints" form="myForm1">Points </label><input id="txtPoints" value="<?php echo $txtPoints; ?>" autocomplete="on" maxlength="3" size="3" required="required" form="myForm1" name="txtPoints" type="text"><br>
                <label id="lblAdminID" for="txtAdminID" form="myForm1">Admin ID </label><input id="txtAdminID" value="" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" size="10" form="myForm1" name="txtAdminID" type="password"><br>
                <input form="myForm1" value="submit" name="Submit" type="submit"><br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php    
  }
  else {
    // We are good to add the info to the database.
    // first set some variables for the database connection. You can change these for your system
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "tasks";
    $password = "YourPassWordHere";
    $dbname = "tasks";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    // Create the SQL query string to add the data
    $sql = "INSERT INTO transaction (id_child, id_task, points)
    VALUES ('".$id_child."', '".$id_task."', '".(int)$txtPoints."' )";
    // Run the SQL query and check result
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $msg = "Details added";
    } else {
        $msg = "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    // Close the mySQL connection
    $conn->close();  
    // Get some human readable versions of child and task to display later
    switch ($id_child) {
        case 1 : $child = "Trevor";
        break;
        case 2 : $child = "Patty";
        break;
        case 3 : $child = "Aaron";
        break;
        case 4 : $child = "Elian";
        break;
    }  
    switch ($id_task) {
        case 1 : $task = "Wash dishes";
        break;
        case 2 : $task = "Clean room";
        break;
        case 3 : $task = "Put out trash";
        break;
        case 4 : $task = "Mow lawn";
        break;
        case 5 : $task = "Water garden";
        break;
        case 6 : $task = "Special task";
        break;  
    }
    // we now display the results with a fresh form for next transaction
    echoHTMLHead("Tasks and Rewards - Success");
?>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <p id="success"><?php echo $msg; ?></p>
            <p>
                Person: <?php echo $child; ?><br />
                Task: <?php echo $task; ?><br />
                Points awarded: <?php echo $txtPoints; ?><br />
            </p>
            <form id="myForm2" accept-charset="utf8" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="myForm2"> 
                <label id="lblPerson" for="id_child" form="myForm2">Person </label> 
                <select id="id_child" form="myForm2" name="id_child">
                    <option selected="" value="0">Select from the list...</option>
                    <option value="1">Trevor</option>
                    <option value="2">Patty</option>
                    <option value="3">Aaron</option>
                    <option value="4">Elian</option>
                </select><br />
                <label id="lblTask" for="id_task" form="myForm2">Task </label>
                <select id="id_task" form="myForm2" name="id_task">
                    <option selected="" value="0">Select from the list...</option>
                    <option value="1">Wash dishes</option>
                    <option value="2">Clean room</option>
                    <option value="3">Put out trash</option>
                    <option value="4">Mow lawn</option>
                    <option value="5">Water garden</option>
                    <option value="6">Special task</option>
                </select><br />
                <label id="lblPoints" for="txtPoints" form="myForm2">Points </label>
                <input id="txtPoints" autocomplete="on" maxlength="3" size="3" required="required" form="myForm2" name="txtPoints" type="text"><br>
                <label id="lblAdminID" for="txtAdminID" form="myForm2">Admin ID </label>
                <input id="txtAdminID" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" size="10" form="myForm2" name="txtAdminID" type="password"><br>
                <input form="myForm2" value="submit" name="Submit" type="submit"><br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php    
  }
}  // if ((isset($_POST['id_task'])) && (isset($_POST['txtPoints'])) && (isset($_POST['txtAdminID'])))
else {
  /* This is the first run of this file so display the initial form for user to complete */
  echoHTMLHead("Tasks and Rewards - Data entry");
?>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <form id="myForm3" accept-charset="utf8" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="on" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="myForm3"> 
                <label id="lblPerson" for="id_child" form="myForm3">Person 
                <select required id="id_child" form="myForm3" name="id_child">
                    <option value="">Select from the list...</option>
                    <option value="1">Trevor</option>
                    <option value="2">Patty</option>
                    <option value="3">Aaron</option>
                    <option value="4">Elian</option>
                </select></label><br />
                <label id="lblTask" for="id_task" form="myForm3">Task </label>
                <select required id="id_task" form="myForm3"  name="id_task">
                    <option value="">Select from the list...</option>
                    <option value="1">Wash dishes</option>
                    <option value="2">Clean room</option>
                    <option value="3">Put out trash</option>
                    <option value="4">Mow lawn</option>
                    <option value="5">Water garden</option>
                    <option value="6">Special task</option>
                </select><br />
                <label id="lblPoints" for="txtPoints" form="myForm3">Points </label><input id="txtPoints" autocomplete="on" maxlength="3" size="3" required="required" form="myForm3" name="txtPoints" type="text"><br>
                <label id="lblAdminID" for="txtAdminID" form="myForm3">Admin ID </label><input id="txtAdminID" autocomplete="off" maxlength="10" size="10" required="required" form="myForm3" name="txtAdminID" type="password"><br>
                <input form="myForm3" value="submit" name="Submit" type="submit"><br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this answer, it has been a great help. I just have one more question regarding this code. When i link the id_task to my main home.php file, it only shows up as the number (e.g 1 for the first task, instead of the actual first task), how could i get it to show up as the actual wording? Again, thank you so much for this code, it has been an enormous help

Comment: Do something like what is about 2/3 way down the code using switch ($id_task) with a few case statements. It essentially converts $id_task (a number) to $task a human readable name.

Comment: Your code now works perfectly, everything is fully functioning, thank you so much. Just wondering, is to possible to make another function, like totalPoints, which basically adds all the id_points together under the same id_child